# libcurl return "couldn't resolve host name"

Tags: curl

I have build a CGI Server, and I want to make a request to it.

**In my testing computer, I add a dns of the CGI Server to "/etc/hosts". "ping" and "curl" command is ok! But, when I make a request in my c codes using libcurl library, an error appeared with "Couldn't resolve host name".**

Then, I found that the "nscd" service doesn't exist in my computer. When I re-install "nscd", libcurl working well.

**I don't know why libcurl is rely on "nscd", while "ping" and "curl" working well without "nscd"??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why libcurl relying on nscd. But I have solved this problem by building libcurl with c-ares library.